# Pass args to Main(string[] args)

Tags: c#, .net, process, .net-core, args

I am trying to build a Console Application to start my .NetCore Web Applications that I've got built as a .dll

Unfortunately the Args entered in the ProcessStartInfo are not being received by my application, however my application does start and i get a unexpected behaviour in the Console.WriteLine Method.

This code is inside my SocketAPI Project which is a .NetCore 2.2 WebApplication | API Project:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Outputs -> Received :
    // ?? Why is args.Length empty? Not even 0 or null??
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Received : ",args.Length));

    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

It gets declared and called by my ProcessRunner which is a Class that holds the current Process:

I am also referring to this documentation:
[dotnet command documentation on microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet?tabs=netcore21)

Which describes: `dotnet [command] [arguments]`

This Code is inside the ProcessRunner Constructor

```
ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "dotnet",
    Arguments = string.Format("BHR.{0}.dll {1}", Name, args),
    WorkingDirectory = ".\\",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};
```

Later on I'm calling `Process.Start();` inside the ProcessRunner to start the Process.

As said I do get Output but no Args... So why do i see "Received :" but nothing on the end?

Do i have to enable my SocketAPI to receive args when starting them as a process? I've been trying to deal with the problem since 2 days now and I'm completely clueless...

Kind Regards

Comment: `"Received : "` -> `"Rece{0}ived : "`

Comment: @PetSerAl what?

Comment: @PetSerAl After looking through it again i recognized what you were trying to tell me! O.c. your answer is also true! Thank you for the advice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are not adding a placeholder for the argument length.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Received: {0} ",args.Length));
```

FYI, This works for me:

```
var arguments = "myarg1 myarg2";
var dir = @"C:\somedir\somechilddir";

var info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("dotnet", $"someproject.dll {arguments}");

info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WorkingDirectory = dir;

var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = info;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Perhaps, try resolving your working directory using Path.GetFullPath();

Comment: I tried your example... And i added GetFullPath but that didn't work. the args are still not passed :(

Comment: What kind of Project is the "someproject.dll"?

Comment: A console application.

Comment: I feel so dull, you are right:

In your code you are not adding a placeholder for the argument length!

Oh wow :D

Comment: Mate I'd like to buy you a Coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you to @AlexanderHiggins for showing me how dull i should feel now!

> In your code you are not adding a placeholder for the argument length.
>
> Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Received: {0} ",args.Length));

Sorry for bothering!

Comment: We've all been there.